# "\vspace" not working in a 2-column document created with "paracol"

Tags: white-space, paracol

In the following MWE, I have a 2-column document (created with [`paracol`](https://mirror.foobar.to/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/paracol/paracol-man.pdf)) where I tried to add both:

- a vertical whitespace between the top margin and the "Header", which worked by using `\vspace*{0.5cm}`, and
- a vertical whitespace between the "Header" and the "Sub-Header", still using `\vspace*{0.5cm}`. However, that command did not work, and no whitespace was created between the "Header" and the "Sub-Header".

How to add a whitespace between the "Header" and the "Sub-Header" in my MWE?

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
    \lipsum[1]
\switchcolumn
    \vspace*{0.5cm}
    {\LARGE Header}
    \newline
    \vspace*{0.5cm}
    {\Large Sub-Header}
    \newline
    \lipsum[1]
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Short answer: `\newline` doesn't put TeX in the mode needed for `\vspace` to work.  You need `\par`.  (See the answer to the question referenced in the previous comment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should finish the paragraph before switching back to a different font size. Otherwise the line spacing in your header will be wrong.

As a side effect, you'll also be able to add vertical space:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
    \lipsum[1]
\switchcolumn
    \vspace*{0.5cm}
    {\LARGE Header\par}
    \vspace*{0.5cm}
    {\Large Sub-Header\par}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Sam! (+1)

Comment: @Ommo You're welcome!